# Can stopping a backup job while its in progress affect future backup jobs?

Tags: sql-server, backup

Can stopping a backup job while its in progress affect future backup jobs? i stopped a backup because it was taking too long and affecting production, and since then all my backup jobs have failed. any way forward? i have already tried deleting the backup jobs and creating new ones and still no luck

Comment: Error messages?

Comment: Message
The job failed.  The Job was invoked by Schedule 278 (FullBackup_Weekly).  The last step to run was step 1 (Subplan_1).

Comment: Assumption: There is just enough space for backups, and the last step of the job is to delete prior backups.  (so keeping just the most recent N).  Check to see if you have enough space in the target folder.  You may need to manually delete some older files to make room.

Comment: you have to retrieve the actual error messgae from the job step^ http://prntscr.com/p6tl42

Comment: ... and also check the errorlog file for relevant messages around that date/time.